# Effect Modification, Confounding, and Correlation

Tags: interaction, confounding

I am trying to estimate the effect of a policy intervention (X) on patient outcome(Y) from an administrative data. In the data set, around 20% of the patients have received the intervention. Even though the intervention is available for all patients admitted to a hospital, I noticed patients who stayed longer are more likely to get the intervention (so X and length of stay (LOS) are correlated). I also suspect X has higher effect for patients who stayed long (say >5) than for patients who stayed for few days. If that is the case, given limited resources, it makes sense to target the intervention on patients who stayed long (say more than 5 days). I wanted to show, controlling for other factors, the effect of X on Y is higher for patients with long LOS than short LOS (let's say we define short < 5 days). The association between Y and LOS seems weak (so I probably can ignore it). Originally, I wanted to model this with an interaction:

Y= b0 + b1*X + b2*LongLOS + b3 *(X*LongLOS) + b4*[other excoriates).

However, since x and LOS are correlated, I am concerned, this will not measure the effect of X correctly. One alternative I considered is estimating a separate model for patients with Long LOS and short LOS and compare the effect of X from the two models. However, this is not the most efficient way of estimating the effect. Given that X and LOS are correlated, what other alternatives do I have?

Thanks,

Comment: What makes you think a correlation between X and LOS will interfere with your estimates?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation between X and LOS is irrelevant and will not affect your estimates except to increase their uncertainty. Running this model (without the interaction between X and LOS) in each group separately and then comparing the differences in the coefficient of X on LOS is identical to running the model with the interaction in the full sample (as long as you include interactions between LOS and all of the other covariates) and examining the size and significance of the X by LOS interaction coefficient.

Comment: Noah, thank you very much for your feedback. May be I should clarify my concern. So let's say I have defined long LOS as staying more than 5 days. So it is a binary variable with 1 for long stay and zero for short stay. The proportion of patients with X is higher in those with Long LOS than those with short stay. In this case, can the model differentiate between the effect of X and Long LOS, since both are correlated?

Comment: Yes, because the interpretation of the coefficient on X is the effect of X holding constant LOS. That means the effect of LOS is controlled for. This is the very point of including LOS in the regression model. If LOS were not in the regression model, then your concerns would be warranted.